# How do I stop window scrollable in phoneGap (iphone)?

Tags: iphone, jquery-mobile, cordova, scroll

I am using phoneGap and [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/). When I use a `<div></div>` tag then it works properly but on an iPhone it is auto scroll-able. How do I stop this?

Comment: Hi, @ghostCoder Thanx for response .! 
i want to make window or in this window add a scrollView. But my header or footer is fixed(it never scrollable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to prevent a div to scroll use this:

`<div id="container" ontouchmove="touchMove(event);">
content goes here
</div>`

and the function `touchMove(event)`:

`touchMove = function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
}`

hope this works

Comment: yes, this is working. 
but, i want only me <header> or <footer> is not move..
(in this situation my all view is fixed)

Comment: if your `<header>` and `<footer>` are both `<div>`container than use this `<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">` if this works please accept the answer ;)